# Accordion to open/close divs

Tags: jquery, accordion

I'm setting up an accordion which needs to open/close all divs within with class side-nav-block-item once clicking the h3 (regardless of how many there are.) I can't modify the structure of the HTML, only add classes.

HTML structure:

```
<div class="side-nav">

<div class="side-nav-item">
<h3>Title</h3>
<div class="side-nav-block-item">content</div>
<div class="side-nav-block-item">content</div>
</div>

<div class="side-nav-item">
<h3>Title</h3>
<div class="side-nav-block-item">content</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Jquery (my failed attempt)

```
    $('.side-nav h3').addClass('on');
//ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION (ON CLICK DO THE FOLLOWING)
$('.side-nav h3').click(function() {

    //REMOVE THE ON CLASS FROM ALL BUTTONS
    $('.side-nav h3').removeClass('on');

    //NO MATTER WHAT WE CLOSE ALL OPEN SLIDES
    $('.side-nav-block-item').slideUp('normal');

    //IF THE NEXT SLIDE WASN'T OPEN THEN OPEN IT
    if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {

        //ADD THE ON CLASS TO THE BUTTON
        $(this).next().addClass('on');

        //OPEN THE SLIDE
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
     } 


 });
```

Comment: You are trying to make it so that no matter what <h3>Title</h3> you click on, every 'content' section closes?

Comment: No just the side-nav-block-items class(s) within the side-nav the h3 is also a child of.

Comment: Check out the jsFiddle I posted, I think it's what you are trying to accomplish. If not let please let me know what I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, no need to check if the next header is hidden, just check if `.side-nav h3` has class `.on`. If it does, remove the class and `slideUp`. If it does not, add the class and `slideDown`.

Take a look at this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CF8LM/). It should accomplish what you want.

```
$('.side-nav h3').addClass('on');
$('.side-nav h3').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('on')) {
        // Remove class
        $(this).toggleClass('on');
        // Slide up the siblings of the header that was clicked
        $(this).siblings('.side-nav-block-item').slideUp('normal');
    } else {
        // Add class
        $(this).toggleClass('on');
        // Slide down the siblings of the header that was clicked
        $(this).siblings('.side-nav-block-item').slideDown('normal');
    }
});
```

**Update**

Here is an updated [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4UMLG/).

Comment: Thank you that gets me a good way there. It is closing all 'side-nav-block-item' whereas I need it to just open/close the ones inside the same 'side-nav-item' as the h3 that is clicked.

Comment: @sarah3585 Please see my update. I added a new jsFiddle and adjusted the code so it only opens/closes the content of the clicked header